# Empty result when trying populate drop list using AJax and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a drop list using Ajax and JQuery, but no result because of the accent character and some special characters that I detected when I limit query to some row without the accent I get some results. This is my code:

JS:

```
var descwr=document.getElementById("descwr").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("descwr").innerHTML="<select  id='descwr_text' ><option value='"+id+"'>"+codewr+" "+descwr+"</option></select>";


$.getJSON("get-data.php?d=car",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,value) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#descwr_text").append($("<option></option>").val(value.ID).html(value.Code+"/"+value.Description));
    });
});
```

php:

```
if(isset($_GET['d'])){  
    $dat=$_GET['d'];
    if($dat=="car"){
        $q = "SELECT ID,Code,Description from vehicules limit ";
        $sql = mysql_query($q);
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,true)){
            $data[] = $row; 
        };
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: NO french accent like this é

Comment: i was kidding :)) but nice info, does your database accept this type of encoding?

Comment: yes the caractor show correctly in database

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: don't use `mysql_*` function use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`  the functions u using have been depreciated and totally removed in new php versions, you wasting your time with them and everyone else's time on this site

Comment: no nothing in console

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)